# maven fundamentals: how can adding a new dependency cause a class not to be found

Tags: java, maven

Suppose I have a multi-module maven project.  There's a class in module A that I want to access from module B.  No problem!  I'll just add module A to module B's pom.xml file.  But when I try to do that, code in module C stops compiling.  In particular, in module C we have

```
// some-file.java in module C
import some.third.party.lib.SomeClass; // suddenly this class is not found on the class path!
```

I can't quite call this "spooky action at a distance" because module C does indeed indirectly depend on module B, whose pom I just changed.  But this still makes no sense.  Adding a dependency can dump more things onto the class path, but it shouldn't ever REMOVE things from the class path, right?  How is this even possible?

Comment: It’s possible that this could change the version of the third party JAR that is resolved. There’s not enough information in the question to give a definite answer. Try running `mvn dependency:tree` and include the results in the question text.

Comment: The third party jar simply vanished from the tree.  It did not get replaced with a different version.

Comment: How was it brought into the tree in the first place? Does C declare a direct dependency on the library, or was it getting it transitively? If transitively, it could also be because of a changed version of some other library that depended on it. It's best to directly declare any dependencies that your code actually imports.

Comment: note: made slight edit to question: got A and B mixed up in one spot

Comment: (one more edit where I got A and B mixed up)

Comment: It was transitive, and I agree that direct would have been better.  But I still don't see what went wrong here.  At the end of the transitive chain, we reach module D, which depends on E, which is the third party library of interest.  After adding A to B's pom, we still have module C depending on D via a transitive chain.  But for some reason, it can no longer reach E via D.  It's as if the tree just stops at D.

Comment: to clarify my last comment: the tree does NOT actually stop at D... plenty of other things from D do show up; but not that one

Comment: Without more specifics, all we can do is guess what the problem is. Can you include the dependency tree from before and after the change in the question?

Comment: It’s kind of huge and I’m not sure if company policy allows me to do that